# Implicit ConfigurationElementCollection sections

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, attributes, custom-configuration

The `System.Configuration` connection string configuration classes define:

```
ConnectionStringsSection : ConfigurationSection

ConnectionStringSettingsCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection

ConnectionStringSettings : ConfigurationElement
```

But the section in the config file looks like:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Foo" connectionString="Whatever" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

so it appears that the `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` is implicit.

I would like to have this same behaviour in my own configuration section to remove a redundant level of nesting, but I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decorate your default collection with the appropriate [ConfigurationProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationpropertyattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("", Options = ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsDefaultCollection)]
```

Comment: And then do I use empty string in the indexer as well? e.g. `public DonkeyCollection Donkeys { get { return (DonekyCollection)base[""]; } }` This seems to work but it looks kinda weird. Thanks